# Google maps and CSS zoom

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps, css, google-maps-api-3

i have a map div that i want to zoom out. here is how i did it

```
<div style="
-moz-transform: scale(0.60);
-webkit-transform: scale(0.60);
-o-transform: scale(0.60);
-ms-zoom:0.60;">
<div id="map" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></div>
</div>
```

so as you see i want to zoom out to 60%. works perfectly in firefox, chrome, opera and safari. BUT there is always explorer... -ms-zoom: 1.0 works since its normal 100%. 2.0 workis since is 200% and so on. but if i try to go below 100% the map div is grayed out and the map is not visible... i tried these variations:

```
-ms-zoom:0.60;
-ms-zoom:0.6;
-ms-zoom:60%;
zoom:0.60;
zoom:0.6;
zoom:60%;
```

and nothing. map is still grayed out... the div gets smaller but i dont understand why the map is not visible. im using api V2, but i tryed with V3 and got the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just found the solution 2 mins after i posted the question. sorry for that. the answer is

```
-ms-transform: scale(0.60);
```

i tested this in newest browser, still dont know if it works in older versions. im gonna test it and post the results here

Answer (score 3):

You should not use css zoom for zooming Google Maps. Instead, use the MapOptions as described in the [Maps Documentation V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions).

Comment: im not trying to zoom only the map, there is also some content arround that i need to zoom out. basicly i found the answer already